# Could I create a mutually referenced sqlalchemy classes across multiple files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

How to create sqlalchemy mutual referencing classes across multiple files?

I have been searching for examples all over the web, but most of the examples put mutual referenced classes in one single files.  However, to achieve modular design, I need to separate each classes in their own files.  This is a similar example on tutorialpoint, the relationship is department has many employees, and some employee could work in more than one departments.

If I put everything into one file (as followed), it will run, but I cannot figure out how to split the Employee and Department into 2 separate files.  I keep getting NameError.

My question is, if it is possible to separate them into department.py, employee.py, link.py, and main.py where department only contain department class and employee only contain employee class?

This is the working code in one single file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Employee(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'employee'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String)
   departments = relationship('Department',secondary='link')

class Department(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'department'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String)
   employees = relationship('Employee', secondary = 'link')

class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'link'
    department_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('department.id'),primary_key = True)
    employee_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('employee.id'),primary_key = True)
```

and main file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String

from employee import Employee, Department, Link
#from department import Department
#from link import Link

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

if __name__=='__main__':

    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mycollege.db', echo = True)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
    session = Session()

    for x in session.query( Department, Employee).filter(Link.department_id == Department.id, 
       Link.employee_id == Employee.id).order_by(Link.department_id).all():
       print ("Department: {} Name: {}".format(x.Department.name, x.Employee.name))
```

This is the SQL to create mycollege.db on SQLite3

```
-- File generated with SQLiteStudio v3.2.1 on Sun Aug 18 21:18:42 2019
--
-- Text encoding used: System
--
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Table: department
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS department;

CREATE TABLE department (
    id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        id
    )
);

INSERT INTO department (
                           id,
                           name
                       )
                       VALUES (
                           1,
                           'Accounts'
                       );

INSERT INTO department (
                           id,
                           name
                       )
                       VALUES (
                           2,
                           'Sales'
                       );

INSERT INTO department (
                           id,
                           name
                       )
                       VALUES (
                           3,
                           'Marketing'
                       );


-- Table: employee
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employee;

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        id
    )
);

INSERT INTO employee (
                         id,
                         name
                     )
                     VALUES (
                         1,
                         'John'
                     );

INSERT INTO employee (
                         id,
                         name
                     )
                     VALUES (
                         2,
                         'Graham'
                     );

INSERT INTO employee (
                         id,
                         name
                     )
                     VALUES (
                         3,
                         'Tony'
                     );


-- Table: link
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS link;

CREATE TABLE link (
    department_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    employee_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (
        department_id,
        employee_id
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        department_id
    )
    REFERENCES department (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (
        employee_id
    )
    REFERENCES employee (id) 
);

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     1,
                     2
                 );

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     3,
                     1
                 );

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     2,
                     3
                 );

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     1,
                     1
                 );

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     2,
                     2
                 );

INSERT INTO link (
                     department_id,
                     employee_id
                 )
                 VALUES (
                     3,
                     3
                 );


COMMIT TRANSACTION;

PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

this is the output for one single file:

```
2019-08-18 21:12:18,999 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-08-18 21:12:19,045 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-08-18 21:12:19,049 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS VARCHAR(60)) AS anon_1
2019-08-18 21:12:19,053 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2019-08-18 21:12:19,059 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2019-08-18 21:12:19,066 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT department.id AS department_id, department.name AS department_name, employee.id AS employee_id, employee.name AS employee_name 
FROM department, employee, link 
WHERE link.department_id = department.id AND link.employee_id = employee.id ORDER BY link.department_id
2019-08-18 21:12:19,072 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
Department: Accounts Name: John
Department: Accounts Name: Graham
Department: Sales Name: Graham
Department: Sales Name: Tony
Department: Marketing Name: John
Department: Marketing Name: Tony
```

error message if I split it into employee, department, link, and main:

```
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\clsregistry.py", line 294, in __call__
    x = eval(self.arg, globals(), self._dict)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'link' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\jcych\Dev\Python\alc\main2.py", line 17, in <module>
    for x in session.query( Department, Employee).filter(Link.department_id == Department.id,
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1544, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 168, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 200, in _set_entities
    self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 231, in _set_entity_selectables
    ent.setup_entity(*d[entity])
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 4084, in setup_entity
    self._with_polymorphic = ext_info.with_polymorphic_mappers
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 855, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 2135, in _with_polymorphic_mappers
    configure_mappers()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3229, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1947, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\interfaces.py", line 196, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1860, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1889, in _process_dependent_arguments
    setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\clsregistry.py", line 306, in __call__
    % (self.prop.parent, self.arg, n.args[0], self.cls)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Employee->employee, expression 'link' failed to locate a name ("name 'link' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'employee.Employee'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.

this is one of the combinations that I tried and it gave the NameError:

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker

from link import *
from employee import *

class Department(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'department'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = Column(String)
   employees = relationship('Employee', secondary = 'link')

if __name__=='__main__':

   engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mycollege.db', echo = True)
   Session = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
   session = Session()
   for x in session.query(Department).filter(Department.id==1).all():
      print(x.id, x.name)
```

Comment: Hi, you can definitely split your models across different modules, even libraries. It would be more helpful here if your example code shows us the configuration that doesn't work for you so that we can reproduce the issue exactly as you experience it.

Comment: In your split configuration did you import the `Link` model before using the models? The error would seem to indicate that the metadata is missing the `link` table definition, required as the secondary by your relationships.

Comment: I tried splitting the file into different stand-alone files, but each seems to have their own problems 
1. only Department in department.py and Empolyee in employee.py - it cannot run due to missing 'Link', 'Department', and 'Employee'
2. import Link and Employee into department.py - NameError: 'link' not defined
3. copy link into department.py and import Employee.  this works for employee, but cannot do the same to department as link will be duplicated
I can implement my own lazy load get_Employees() in Department class